# MediaElement on Windows 10 build 10240

Tags: windows, media, mediaelement, wmp

It seems like I'm the only one who am facing this issue !
After installing the latest and final build of Windows 10, I noticed that Windows Media Player has gone ! So I can't continue developing my WPF project based on MediaElement which needs WMP to work correctly.
I looked everywhere to figure out this issue but with no result.
Thank you helping me, I just want somebody to confirm that WMP isn't anymore present in this version of Windows, otherwise, how to recover it or how to make MediaElement return to work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now, Microsoft just released the Media Feature Pack for Windows 10
My project works correctly now.